# File navigation for video

Tags: html, reactjs, video

In my website, I wanted to add a background video for my container. The location of my video is found here: [File Path of Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C31xC.png)

The way to access the video is `<video src="videos/video-2.mp4" autoPlay loop muted />`.
But, I thought it would be `<video src="/public/videos/video-2.mp4" autoPlay loop muted />`.

I was wondering why the first file navigation works, while the second file navigation does not work. How does the computer know to search in the public folder, but when I try to specify to look in the public folder then it does not work?

Comment: everything is relative to the root path for the website. if the root path (where your default web page is served from) then the path to video will be from the same point

Answer (score 1):

The public folder is somewhere the computer looks for resource files by default. It cannot be named anything other than "public". That's why the computer doesn't really need you to include it in the navigation path.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).